# Try catch logic error...Try Catch wont pull full index

Tags: java, try-catch

Can someone please help me figure out this try catch problem I'm having. I need to have the throw activate only after we know that the certain option is not listed in the array. For example, if the user enters a 9 in for Powertrain and there are only 2 options available.

List Example:
Powertrain
1 Automatic 7500.00
2 Manual 5000.00
Seat
1 Multi-Point 800.00
2 Heated 1200.00
3 Air 2000.00

Instead of checking both indexes it is calling the Execption method twice. Here is an example of the problem im facing. The 9 is where Powertrain options are located so I would think it would check Powertrain options 1 and 2, then realize its not in there however it seems to stop after each check. Im very new to using Exceptions so any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Product Identification Code: 
110111911111
OptionsNotFoundException: Options available are Automatic
OptionsNotFoundException: Options available are Manual

UPDATED CODE:

```
 public void setOptions(String o) throws IOException {
        options = new String[]{"Model", "Exterior Color", "Interior Color", "Powertrain", "Seat", "Radio", "Tire", "Rim", "Miscellaneous"};
        //ArrayList to hold the read .txt file
        ArrayList<String> textFile = readConfig(config);//new ArrayList<>();

        //Attempts to catch format error
        try {
            //Calls pidFormat method, then stores the returned array in pIDFormat
            int[] pIDFormat = pidFormat(o.charAt(0));
            if (((o.charAt(0) == '1') && (o.length() == 12)) || ((o.charAt(0) == '2') && o.length() == 15) || ((o.charAt(0) == '3') && o.length() == 15)) {
                //Converts pID to formatted style then stores in formattedPID array
                formattedPID = new String[pIDFormat.length];
                int current = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < pIDFormat.length; i++) {
                    formattedPID[i] = o.substring(current, pIDFormat[i]);
                    current = pIDFormat[i];
                }
            } else {
                throw new MakeFormatException(pIDFormat[8]);
            }
        } catch (MakeFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            AnyCarManufacturer.request();
        }

        //Adds the word model to the first index of the arraylist
        textFile.add(0, "Model");

        int index = 0;
        boolean obj = false;
        String[] outOfBounds = new String[80];
        String optionsOutOfBounds = null;
        String optionsOutOfBoundsIndex;
        ArrayList<String>outofBoundsIndex=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < textFile.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (!obj) {
                if (index == options.length) {
                    break;
                } else if (textFile.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(options[index])) {
                    obj = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (index + 1 < options.length && textFile.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(options[index + 1])) {
                    options[index] = options[index] + ": " + "None";
                    index++;
                } else {
                    String[] c = textFile.get(i).split(" ");

                    if (!formattedPID[index].contains(c[0])) {
                        optionsOutOfBoundsIndex = formattedPID[index] + " " + options[index];
                        outofBoundsIndex.add(optionsOutOfBoundsIndex);
                        for (int a = 0; a < c[0].length(); a++) {
                            optionsOutOfBounds = optionsOutOfBounds + " " + c[1];
                            outOfBounds[index] = optionsOutOfBounds;
                        }
                    }



                    if (formattedPID[index].equals(c[0])) {
                        if (!options[index].equals(options[8])) {
                            options[index] = options[index] + ": " + c[1];

                            index++;
                            obj = false;
                        } else if (options[index].equals(options[8])) {
                            options[index] = options[index] + ": ";
                            StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
                            for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
                                if (j % 2 != 0 && j != 0) {
                                    joiner.add(c[j]);
                                    obj = false;
                                }
                            }
                            options[index] = options[index] + joiner;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (obj) {
            options[index] = options[index] + ": None";
        }

        //Second Attempt to Catch Model Error
        try {
            if (options[0].contains("None")) {
                throw new ModelNotFoundException(formattedPID[0], getMake());
            }
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            AnyCarManufacturer.request();
        }



            //This trims down my arraylist of out of bound options
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String text : outOfBounds)
            {
                if (text != null && text.length() > 0)
                {
                    list.add(text);
                    break;
                }
            }
            outOfBounds = list.toArray(new String[0]);
            String[] splitter = new String[2];
            splitter = outofBoundsIndex.get(0).split(" ");
            System.out.println(splitter[0]+" "+splitter[1]);


        //Attempt to Catch Options Error
        if (outOfBounds[0]!=null){
            try {
                throw new OptionsNotFoundException(outOfBounds[0]);
            } catch (OptionsNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                AnyCarManufacturer.request();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Do you want to stop after first exception?

Comment: I would like the output to be so i want Automatic and manual on the same line  OptionsNotFoundException: options available 
are: ” + list of available options for option category (ex: 
Powertrain: automatic, manual”
)

Comment: So do you want your program to throw `OptionsNotFoundException` with the above message ?

Comment: I need the output to have Automatic and manual on the same line though like this....OptionsNotFoundException: options available are: ” + list of available options for option category (ex: Powertrain: automatic, manual” )

Comment: My problem im having is it is throwing the exception twice

Comment: I am not sure, but may be because you are not breaking your `for` loop in the `catch` and in the next iteration you get another exception.

Comment: Any idea how I could go about fixing this issue? Im still new to exceptions so any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Well it depends. When you get an exception do you still want to continue with FOR loop ? If Not You can put a break in the catch block.

Comment: Yes, I need to continue until it goes through all possible options that the current part could have had.  Then i need it to output it like this: OptionsNotFoundException: options available are: ” + list of available options for option category (ex: Powertrain: automatic, manual”       if it just breaks and stops after the first check all i will get is automatic and not automatic and manual on one line. I need both

Comment: Then don't put try/catch inside the FOR loop. In the FOR loop have some flag and prepare error message. Once the FOR loop ends check the flag and if true throw exception with the error mesasge

Comment: I tried to do the flag last night actually. I just updated my code so you can see what it looks like now. When I do it outside of my loop I get an error message saying IndexOutOfBoundsException  I really have no idea what im doing wrong